# Laravel. Почему выводится "validation.required" вместо "The :attribute field is required."?

Tags: php, laravel, валидация, php7

Доброго времени суток!

Я сделал валидацию данных из формы по документации, но выводится не то что мне нужно.

Мне нужно вывести ошибку в случае, если были отправлены пустые значения из формы.

Но текст ошибки приходит такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя по документации, должен прийти такой: "The :attribute field is required."

Кастомная валидация тоже не работает(

Как разрешить эту техническую сложность?

Мой код:

**home.blade.php**

```
<?php
@section('main_content')
    @if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>   
        @endforeach
        </ul>

    </div>
    @endif

    <form action="/message/check" method="post">
        @csrf
        <input class="form-control mb-2" type="text" name="name_field" id="name_field" placeholder="Введиет имя" >
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message_field" id="message_field" placeholder="Введите сообщение" ></textarea><br>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
@endsection
```

**MainController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Test;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function home() {
        return view('home');
    }

    public function database() {
        
        $messages = new Test();
        return view('database', ['messages' => $messages->all()]);
    }

    public function message_check(Request $request) {

        $validation = $request->validate([
            'name_field' => 'required',
            'message_field' => 'required',
        ]);
    

        $review = new Test();
        $review->name = $request->input('name_field');
        $review->message = $request->input('message_field');

        $review->save();
        return redirect()->route('database');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас поля в форме называются `name_field` и `message_field`, а проверяете Вы `name` и `message`:

```php
$validation = $request->validate([
    'name_field' => 'required',
    'message_field' => 'required',
]);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я поправил, но результат тот же

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задать сообщения об ошибках напрямую, подробнее - https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/validation#%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: К сожалению не сработало(

Answer (score 0):

Так происходит после того как вы добавляете локализацию resources/lang. После того как появляется директория lang в ресурсах ошибки отображаются таким образом